# Reverse phone number search in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-maps

I have an address, a business name, and latitude/longitude coordinates for businesses. Using this, I can form a URL to http://maps.apple.com to open the location in Apple Maps. When the location is opened, Apple Maps shows a phone number for the businesses under details. Is there any way to pull that phone number from Apple Maps and allow the user to directly call the business from inside the app? Or maybe a different way to reverse phone number search in Swift?

Thank you!!

EDIT:

Here's the code I use to open a business in Apple Maps using coordinates and business name:

```
let businessNameEncoded:String = self.annotationSelectedTitle.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+")
let urlString:String = "http://maps.apple.com/?q=" + businessNameEncoded + "&sll=" + latitude + "," + longitude
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

This code opens the business in Apple Maps. Then you can tap on a pin to see the phone number as shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jilHU.png).

Comment: can you show a specific link for that or even code? what have you tried so far?

Comment: thanks @luk2302 - just edited to add code and a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MKLocalSearch will help.You can get MKMapItem,in which phone number and address info are included.(You could get it using other APIs if there were)